# Datatables column visibility invisibility retained

Tags: datatables

I have these five fields ID, Name, Address, Phone and Fax displaying on the datatable. I am using Column Visibility Feature and by default, I am displaying first four columns. Suppose, I make Fax column Visible and Phone Column Invisible. Now, if I refresh the page, I see the same four columns again. My question is, can we Retain this visibility / invisibility ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refresh the page? Do you mean redraw the datatables page? (e.g. by clicking a column header to sort or clicking 'next' in the datatable?)

If so, are you using javascript/jquery to modify the visibility of your elements?

Doing so will work initially - but because datatables doesn't 'know' that jquery has modified the element, when it redraws the table (in a new order, or on a new page or whatever) it will revert your changes to whatever state it understands the table to be in.

To make your changes persist over redraws, you need to use the  [datatables api](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns%28%29.visible%28%29) - so that datatables knows what you're doing. like this:

```
var mytable= $('#mytable').DataTable();
mytable.column( 0 ).visible( false );
```

**however** IF you want these changes to persist between refreshes of the webpage in the browser, then you need to set up sessions, or store these configurations in a database.

Then every time the page in requested, you check that data, and you can decide dynamically onload how to initialise your datatable:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "aoColumnDefs": [
      { "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [ userHiddenColumn ] }
    ] } );
} );
```

Comment: Refresh the page means go to an other page and then get back to same datatable page. This process refreshes the datatable page. I was thinking the same to store the columns in the DB. Any body else with some other solutions ?

Comment: to make the table remember it's state between sessions/ visits from the user, you need to store the configurations in some sort of database and initialise your table dynamically for each GET. There's lots of ways to do that, but there aren't really any alternative solutions to it...

Comment: We don't need Session / Database to remember the state as its already part of Datatables

stateSave: true,

Please check
https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/column_visibility/stateSave.html

Comment: Hi @AamirSaeed glad you got a solution that works. Keep in mind that statesave uses sessionStorage under the hood. It's still a session and will be lost on cache clearance/browser close.

Comment: Hi @Paul, I have closed the browser and reopened and it still works but it does not work if I clear the Cookies.